# What is the best icon creator for mac?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, icon

I'm new to mac, I used to use Axialis IconWorkshop on Windows. So I want to know what's the best icon creator for mac?

Comment: Hire [Susan Kare](http://www.kare.com) - she's the best icon creator for Mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to Photoshop, then I highly recommend [Iconbuilder from Iconfactory](http://iconfactory.com/software/iconbuilder/). Back when I doing this, Iconbuilder made the creation of resources for a variety of platforms a snap.

Comment: Iconbuilder is not working with PS CS 6

Answer (score 3):

If you just have a `tiff` file that you need to make into an icon, you can use the built-in command line program `tiff2icns`.

(This is probably not the best all-around answer, but it has been useful to me.)

Answer (score 3):

It's been years and things are changing, let me answer my own question, What is the best icon creator for Mac?

I think the answer is `iconutil` for me. You can get more info by running `man iconutil` in Terminal.

I also create an Automator workflow:

https://github.com/sparanoid/automator-workflows#create-app-iconset

You can convert a set of images or a single image to an icon.

Answer (score 3):

Since it isn't mentioned, I'll do it: [IconSlate](https://itunes.apple.com/app/icon-slate/id439697913) is a fantastic app for creating both Windows (`.ico`) and Mac (`.icns`) icons. Simple to use, beautifully designed and does exactly what it says on the tin. Highly recommended!

Answer (score 1):

If you want free software your best choice was [Pic2Icon](http://osxiconeditor.phatcode.net/Pic2Icon.html) and you can also try [img2icnsapp](http://www.img2icnsapp.com/) free version and if you like it, can upgrade it to pro version.

and the best software was [iconeer](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/7891/iconeer) but it's not free and you must pay for it.

I also suggest you see this [page for more infos](http://osxiconeditor.phatcode.net/).

Comment: I tried all these apps and Iconbuilder and found img2icns just fit my need and work fine for me. however Iconbuilder is great too but it's a little expensive.

Comment: The iconeer page is offline.